# Switching workspaces with dual monitors

Tags: 13.04, workspaces

I'm working on Ubuntu 13.04 and have a second monitor connected with a VGA. I currently have the second monitor as an extended screen. I was wondering if there was a way that I could set it up so I could put a window on my second monitor, switch workspaces on my main display and the second monitor display wouldn't change?

I think it was a thing in the past, but I haven't found a solution. I just want my second monitor to be consistent while my main workspace remains dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you want, but you can set "**Always on Visible Workspace**" flag in window options (right click on window caption when window is not in full screen mode and select this option from context menu).

With this flag window will be on the same place on monitor when switching between workspaces.

Comment: good feature. Using it, too.